# Parsing cybersourse Response in PHP

Tags: cybersource

I Need to parse the below array and retrieve values;status,id.

Below is the PHP Array

```
Array ( [0] => CyberSource\Model\PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response Object ( [container:protected] => 
Array ( [links] => CyberSource\Model\PtsV2PaymentsPost201ResponseLinks Object ( [container:protected] => 
    Array ( [self] => CyberSource\Model\PtsV2PaymentsPost201ResponseLinksSelf 
        Object ( [container:protected] => Array ( [href] => /pts/v2/payments/621258854395 [method] => GET ) )
        [reversal] => [capture] => [customer] => [paymentInstrument] => [shippingAddress] => [instrumentIdentifier] => ) ) 
        [id] => 621258854395 
        [submitTimeUtc] => 2021-05-17T13:40:55Z 
        [status] => AUTHORIZED 
        [reconciliationId] => 621258854395 
        [errorInformation] =>...............
```

Below is my php code

```
 $parseApiResponse = new CyberSource\Model\PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response($apiResponse);
    print_r("Status"." ".$parseApiResponse->getStatus());
```

Please assist in resolving this.

Want to do a similar thing as I am able to do in java as below

```
  String status = result.getStatus();
```

Comment: did you solved this problem?

Comment: Not In PHP ended up using Java

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone.  It took me a while to figure this out.  The original poster was so close.  It's just...

`print_r("Status"." ".$apiResponse[0]->getStatus());`

No need to instantiate a new "PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response()".  The response element ([0]) has already done that when you call, "createPayment()", etc.

lib/Model/PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response.php lists all the available getters.  getId(), getStatus(), getLinks(),etc.

Answer (score 0):

$parseApiResponse = new CyberSource\Model\PtsV2PaymentsPost201Response($apiResponse);

$result =  \GuzzleHttp\json_decode( $parseApiResponse[0] , true );

return = $result['links'];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).